# Does go's protobuf implementation support DynamicMessage?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Specifically, I'd like to serialize a Go struct without a corresponding .proto file, and then deserialize it (also without a .proto file) and programmatically query and extract its fields.

A [search](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/search?q=dynamicmessage) of the golang implementation turns up no equivalent functionality.

Is this supported?

(while encoding/gob supports this, I need multi-language compatibility)

Comment: as i know, it not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authors say that this isn't supported:

https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/106